# phpmailer send function does not return a value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I have this piece of code here and phpmailer send function does not return true or false so the following is not working. JSON is ok and tested on other functions. I pinpointed the problem on mail->send. Mail is working and is sent to the email address but I do not get a return value. The code is a php file called form jquery as an ajax call. If anybody can help thanks in advance.

```
    if( !$mail->Send() )
{
    // return 0 for failure
    $data[] = array("result" => 0 );
}
else
{
    // return 1 for success
    $data[] = array("result" => 1 );
}
```

Comment: Test it in isolation, outside your ajax setup. `send()` does return a boolean; if it's not, are you sure it's returning at all? Check your web server logs for errors.

Comment: json returns --- JSON.parse Error: Unexpected input at position:5

Comment: Sigh. This is exactly what I meant by "test it in isolation". Look at the *actual* return value *before* you try to parse it as JSON. It probably contains some error message that isn't in JSON format.

Comment: tried this ---  $result = $mail->Send(); and put it directly in a php file with no ajax call and it returns [{"result":1}] which is fine ... but in an ajax call where I need it is not working ... is there a delay in returning the result and the code continues to execute???

Comment: OK, so now you've seen that working, use your web inspector to see exactly what is returned to your ajax call before you try to do anything with it. In Chrome's inspector these will be labelled as XHR requests, and you can simply view the content of the response. Check the headers too - are you setting a correct `application/json` content-type for your JSON responses?

Comment: from XHR --- response = ""

Comment: Do I really have to hand-hold you through every line? You didn't show it in your code - do you actually output the result? I'd expect something like `header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode($data);`.

Comment: :) my friend of course I output the result ... I use the same code up to ten times and its working  ... only this piece here I have a problem ... with mail->send()

Comment: Good - but that's important info you should not have left out. We've already established that it's not `send` that's the problem. Step through it with a debugger; if you don't have one, go download Netbeans or a PHPStorm demo and set it up with xdebug.

Comment: I do not know why but by disabling $mail->isSMTP(); is working fine ... if anybody know the reason please let us know

Answer (score 1):

if you have a similar problem just disable line $mail->isSMTP(); and its working